# Getting the column 'country_id' in 'where' clause is ambiguous - error in search query in cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am working with CakePHP 1.3 version for search functionality using Search Plugin.

I have three models:

- Demo,
- Country
- State

`Demo` has two foreign keys, `country_id` and `state_id`. `State` has the foreign key `country_id`.

What I am doing is, I have search form which have country & state drop down which fetch all data from countries & states table. When i search any of country from dropdown & submit the form it will show me below error. If i search using only state dropdown i get the correct result.

When I execute the search query, I get the error

> 'Column '`country_id`' in where clause is ambiguous'

My query is:

```
SELECT `Demo`.`id`, `Demo`.`demo2`, `Demo`.`desc`, `Demo`.`subject`, `Demo`.`gender`, `Demo`.`country_id`, `Demo`.`state_id`, `Demo`.`image_url`, `Country`.`id`, `Country`.`name`, `State`.`id`, `State`.`country_id`, `State`.`description` FROM `demos` AS `Demo` LEFT JOIN `countries` AS `Country` ON (`Demo`.`country_id` = `Country`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `states` AS `State` ON (`Demo`.`state_id` = `State`.`id`) WHERE `country_id` = 2
```

Model relationships in Demo table:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Country' => array(
        'className' => 'Country',
        'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),

    'State' => array(
        'className' => 'State',
        'foreignKey' => 'state_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);
```

The controller query to fetch all Country in dropdown is:

> $country=$this->Country->find('list');     //just display the list of country in dropdown

The query search the data from all fields except `Country` (`country_id`), because it will not know which `country_id` it is looking for from table `Demo` or table `State`. I need the `country_id` from the demo table to get the correct result.

Comment: What does your `find()` statement look like? The error is, likely, in the conditions you're passing to `find` ...

Comment: Find statement for country in Demo controller is $country=$this->Country->find('list');

Comment: So where is it getting the `country_id = 2` condition? Are you not passing an array of conditions in?

Comment: Hey! I am using the search plugin to get the search result.

Comment: @parthvishah: Have you tried my answer? I still think that's the solution to your problem..

Comment: @dr Hannibal Lecter : I tried yor solution & it's not working for me. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @parthvishah: Did you make the changes for all your relations and queries? Did you get a new error or is it still the same?

Comment: @dr Hannibal Lecter : I changed it for all relation & it generate the new error as below & the old one is as it is: Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Demo.Demo.country_id' in 'on clause' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]

Comment: @parthvishah: Well that sucks..I'll vote to delete my answer then, I hope you find a solution.

Comment: @dr Hannibal Lecter : Still not get the solution, currently i manually concate Demo before the country_id to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want to make a find over Demo for a specific `country_id`.
Well you should define which "country_id" you're using because more than one of those tables 
has such a column.

Just use `Demo`.`country_id` in the conditions array:

```
array('conditions' => array('Demo.country_id' => 2));
```

And you should see some SQL generated by Cake like this:

```
SELECT `Demo`.`id`, `Demo`.`demo2`, `Demo`.`desc`, `Demo`.`subject`, `Demo`.`gender`, `Demo`.`country_id`, `Demo`.`state_id`, `Demo`.`image_url`, `Country`.`id`, `Country`.`name`, `State`.`id`, `State`.`country_id`, `State`.`description` FROM `demos` AS `Demo` LEFT JOIN `countries` AS `Country` ON (`Demo`.`country_id` = `Country`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `states` AS `State` ON (`Demo`.`state_id` = `State`.`id`) WHERE `Demo`.`country_id` = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
Demo.id,
Demo.demo2,
Demo.desc,
Demo.subject,
Demo.gender,
Demo.country_id,
Demo.state_id,
Demo.image_url,
Country.id,
Country.name,
State.id,
State.country_id,
State.description

FROM demos AS Demo
LEFT JOIN countries AS Country ON (Demo.country_id = Country.id)
LEFT JOIN states AS State ON (Demo.state_id = State.id) WHERE Demo.country_id = 2
```

Comment: Yes i know it will come this way, but query is dynamic & i cant add model name statically. Do you know how i can do the same dynamically as i am not passing the static query, cake is generating query for me.